# Is that phrase "a type of animal" grammatically correct? Or "a type of an animal"?

Tags: articles

My name is Edith. I have started to learn grammar again these days. I found it hard actually. There are so many rules in grammar books.

I saw an example in the book which is " The giraffe is a type of animal.' Why don't we use "The giraffe is a type of an animal?"

I saw another example which is " The owner of the restaurant is Lucy." Why can we use the after the owner of?

How can we call "a type of", "a branch of", "a bowl of", "a slice of" in general?

Thank you for your generous help:)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that StackExchange is a network of Q&A sites, not discussion forums. As such, it is best to ask only one question at a time, explaining in full what problem you are having. If English is not your mother tongue, I might also suggest visiting our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Welcome to ELU. There are rather too many questions here. Either you are asking about *a type of* or you are asking about articles (*a, an the*). Please edit the question to focus only on one aspect. I think it would be better answered elsewhere, so I'm going to put it on hold for now until you can narrow it down, and then it can be migrated.

Comment: These are called **Determiners**. They go before the adjectives in a noun phrase, and they can form quite complex phrases, like the first constituent in _[What seemed to me to be quite a few] [large red brick Regency buildings]_. The second constituent is the adjectives and the noun they modify, and the first one is the determiner phrase. You can have only one determiner in a noun phrase, so you can't say *_the his brother_, since _his_ and _the_ are both determiners.

Comment: You can! There’s nothing wrong with saying “The giraffe is a type of an animal”. Use it if you wish, though “an” is superfluous, the bare noun “animal” being sufficient and the ‘normal’ form. Expressions like “a branch of _the_ tree”; “a bowl of _the_ punch” etc. are just noun phrases with the nouns “branch” and “bowl” functioning as **head** with an _of_ PP as **complement**. There’s nothing wrong with them at all.

Comment: When we talk about universals: "a cat is a mammal", "every cat is a mammal", "every one cat is one of every mammal", ...; we use the indefinite article for convenience, but 'every' is definite -- once we know that every cat is meant, we know where to find/store information about the cat.  "Type of a[n]" means "type of every", and since 'every' is definite, the indefinite article can be omitted, leaving "type of".